# Images missing in 'Getting started webpart' when migrated from 2010 to o365 thru Sharegate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

We are migrating sites thru Sharegate and 'Getting started web part below does not load all the images as below

[difference in Both 2010 and O365 webparts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAYiD.png)

When i open the path of the image in separate window it shows the image as below
[this is the image when opened in new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heOQ4.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "Getting Started" is quite different from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. Can you please contact support@share-gate.com, and they can help you directly? Thanks!